# What is this brown dust/powder inside my old pack?

Tags: backpacks

I have a Lowe Aline Attack 50 pack from around 2000 and recently much of the inside has accumulated a sort of brown powder that is either, I suspect, some kind of mildew, or the remains of the decomposition of the pack's waterproofing.

[image: mysterious stuff in pack]

The stuff is not easy to remove; if I beat the pack while holding it upside down, the dust gradually falls out. Wiping it down with a damp cloth or cleaner doesn't speed the process up much. The stuff appears to be only on the waterproof liner and, to a much lesser extent, facing surfaces.
What is it? Can it be removed? Is it just time for a new pack?

--

Addendum--
I've already accepted an answer below but wanted to share that Lowe customer support concurs that the waterproof liner has decomposed.

[image: lowe e-mail]

Comment: When you wipe a spot with a damp cloth, what do you get?  Does more of the lining flake off?

Comment: From the picture, it looks like a film that's dry rotting away. I'd say it's the water proofing. Goretex is known not to last long.

Comment: @ab2 When I wipe it, I get a discolored patch on the rag. In the seams, where the dust accumulates as something more like 'crud,' I can sometimes scrap some off.

Comment: If it doesn't flake off when you wipe it, it may not be the waterproof lining.  I'd try wiping it down gently with a damp cloth.  Then, if you can,  turn it inside out and store it in a dry place.  And repeat.  If it is the waterproof lining, you will find out by wiping.  If it is mold, this should get rid of at least some of it.

Comment: Looks like the water proofing is breaking down (delaminating).  Store dry, cool, and not compressed to prevent.   I had a North Face VE24 do that after 12 years so I took tent only to the local store and they called me back and said we need the tent poles and rain fly.  I was like why but  took them in.  They gave me a new VE25 tent.  I don't climb anymore but it is awesome car comping tent.  Wash it inside out a few times and you still have a pack with no water proofing.

Comment: I actually have two packs of about this size (50L) and about this age (17-20 years) suffering from this right now. Cleaning them both up is going to be more work than its worth, so I think it's time to step into the 21st century and replace them with a new pack.

Comment: Running them through the washing machine is too much work?

Comment: @Paparazzi Done, made no difference.

Comment: As already said, It is the water proofing breaking down. You cannot fix it. Options are a new pack, or use a pack liner to keep the crud out of the stuff you are carrying. Any 'fix' will be temporary.

Comment: biscuit crumbs?

Comment: most packs are NOT water proof because they don't need to be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a tailor, I would say that it is either the water proofing is breaking down  or if it contains a fabric glue binding two types of fabric together is disintegrating. This is almost impossible to cleanup correctly. Personally I would either use it as it is, if you could use it in some way that such a condition would not be a hindrance for your backpacking, or get rid of it.

You could consider a pack liner (like a large trash-bag inside the bag).

Personally, **I would simply get a new backpack**. Sorry.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely the water-resistant lining on the inside of the fabric breaking down.  I've seen that a number of times.